# MongoDB SELECT field, COUNT GROUP

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to do something like

```
SELECT province, COUNT(distinct id) FROM user GROUP BY province
```

So get something like

```
province -> entries (unique to id)
```

But it seems to be proving to be really difficult. I ended up with

```
db.user.aggregate([
    { $group: { _id: "$id"}  },
    { $group: { _id: "$province", count: { $sum: 1 } } } 
])
```

But that's giving me the total number of distinct ID values, not grouped by province. How can I properly translate that query over to the aggregate function?

Example documents.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("534fd9f7b40801d50b8b4567"),
    "id" : "4",
    "province" : "on",
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("534fd9f7b40801d50b8b4567"),
    "id" : "4",
    "province" : "on",
}
```

Should return

```
on - 1
```

Because there is two rows with the same "id", so we only add 1 to on.

Comment: please add some documents sample and the desired result.

Comment: your SQL query will not run.  when grouping by `id`, you can't select `province`

Comment: Opps, fixed I pasted the wrong query. Fixed.

Comment: np, can you post a sample document from your collection?

Comment: Done, I posted some more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First group on `province` and `id` to get the unique combinations, and then group on just `province` to get the count of `id`s per `province`:

```javascript
db.test.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: {province: '$province', id: '$id'}}},
    {$group: {_id: '$_id.province', count: {$sum: 1}}}
])
```

gives a result of:

```javascript
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "on",
            "count" : 1
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: how can we convert into mongodb if sql like following SELECT province, COUNT(id) FROM user GROUP BY province

Comment: for this same query how can we have count,distinct count in same query for example I want **SELECT province, COUNT(distinct id), COUNT(id) FROM user GROUP BY province.** this sql query I want to convert into mongodb query

Answer (score 0):

One approach to get the results you want would be to use the [`$addToSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) operator, which is used to add only unique values to an array.  The complete query would look like:

```js
db.user.aggregate([
    // Group by "province" and add unique values of "id" to array
    { $group: { 
        _id: "$province", 
        id: { $addToSet: "$id" } 
    }}, 
    // De-normalize the array into separate documents
    {$unwind:"$id"}, 
    // Get the distinct count
    {$group:{_id:"$_id", count:{$sum:1}}}
])
```

If you are using MongoDB 2.6, you can also use the [`$size`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/#exp._S_size) aggregation operator to get the size of the `id` array.