# Select count group by mongodb

Tags: sql, mongodb

I'm trying to convert following sql query into mongodb but I couldn't finish it

```
select campaign_id,campaign_name,count(subscriber_id) 
    group by campaign_id,campaign_name from campaigns;
```

Here is my partial mongodb query

```js
db.campaigns.aggregate([
    {$group: { 
        _id: {campaign_id: "$campaign_id",campaign_name: "$campaign_name"},
        count: {$sum: "$subscriber_id"}
    }}
])
```

Comment: You are doing a count of subscriber_id which is not included in you group by. Did you intend that? Any chance of seeing a couple of sample documents? Also, what is the issue you are facing, and what do you expect to see.

Comment: And the error? That is not getting you a distinct count of subscribers by campaign_id, campaign_name, just to be clear, so you could just as easily sum by $campaign_id.

Comment: @John please check this question this is very similar to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23135704/mongodb-select-field-count-group here I want SELECT province, COUNT(id) FROM user GROUP BY province, only change is I don't want distinct count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To emulate SQL `count(subscriber_id)` you can prepend a `$match` stage to your pipeline to filter out docs where `subscriber_id` is either missing or set to `null` and then you can just use a simple `{$sum: 1}` for your count:

```js
db.campaigns.aggregate([
    {$match: {subscriber_id: {$ne: null}}},
    {$group: { 
        _id: {campaign_id: "$campaign_id",campaign_name: "$campaign_name"},
        count: {$sum: 1}
    }}
])
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, one more question how can we count and distinct count in same query

Comment: @rams That's best asked as a new question as it's non-trivial.

Comment: Thanks for you reply , I asked in separate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24761266/select-group-by-count-and-distinct-count-in-same-mongodb-query