# sailsjs waterline groupBy with sum

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I'm trying to get the students grouped by school and the number of students for each school like so:

```
        return Student.find({ where: {school: schoolIdArray}, groupBy: [ 'school' ], sum: [ 'totalAmt' ] })
          .exec(function(error, response) {
            console.log(response);
          });
```

I keep getting the following:

```
[ { school: '57424c8908d4af812c77a77e', totalAmt: 0 }, etc. ]
```

Why is it that all of the school's count is 0??

I read the below on this:

[Select Group by count and distinct count in same mongodb query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24761266/select-group-by-count-and-distinct-count-in-same-mongodb-query)

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo/blob/master/lib/query/aggregate.js#L43

https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/queries/query-language.md

Is there anything I can do differently for this?

Comment: Sails-mongo driver does not support groupBy. You can use Model.native and than aggregate like in console mode.