# unlimited cursor Mongo DB for java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm traying to all the document with this aggregate query but the problem here that the cursor is limited , he return approximitly 500 results . I tried with `limit(0)`but it doesn't work ! , also i tried with limit(10000) or limit (20000) but it's doesn't work i got always 500 results

```
 AggregateIterable<Document> resultMongo = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
                    Aggregates.match(and(filters)),
                    Aggregates.group(and(eq(CoverageWarningFieldEnum.DT_EXTRACT.getLabel(), "$" + CoverageWarningFieldEnum.DT_EXTRACT.getLabel())
                            , eq(CoverageWarningFieldEnum.ID_SUP_NUMBER.getLabel(), "$" + CoverageWarningFieldEnum.ID_SUP_NUMBER.getLabel())
                            , eq(CoverageWarningFieldEnum.CODE_SUPPLIER_DLPA_SITE.getLabel(), "$" + CoverageWarningFieldEnum.CODE_SUPPLIER_DLPA_SITE.getLabel())
                            , eq(CoverageWarningFieldEnum.SUP_NAME.getLabel(), "$" + CoverageWarningFieldEnum.SUP_NAME.getLabel())
                            , eq(CoverageWarningFieldEnum.MLF07_GRPFOU.getLabel(), "$" + CoverageWarningFieldEnum.MLF07_GRPFOU.getLabel()))
                            , sum("sum_w_ord_unit_ord_min_coverage", "$" + CoverageWarningFieldEnum.W_ORD_UNIT_ORD_MIN_COVERAGE.getLabel())
                            , sum("sum_w_excess_delivery", "$*" + CoverageWarningFieldEnum.W_EXCESS_DELIVERY.getLabel())
                            , sum("sum_w_inventory", "$" + CoverageWarningFieldEnum.W_INVENTORY.getLabel())
                            , sum("sum_w_service_blocking", "$" + CoverageWarningFieldEnum.W_SERVICE_BLOCKING_2.getLabel())
                            , sum("sum_w_service_blocking_4", "$w" + CoverageWarningFieldEnum.W_SERVICE_BLOCKING_4.getLabel())
                            , sum("sum_w_coverage_change", "$" + CoverageWarningFieldEnum.W_COVERAGE_CHANGE.getLabel())
                            , sum("sum_w_pa_supervision", "$" + CoverageWarningFieldEnum.W_PA_SUPERVISION.getLabel())
                            , sum("sum_val_pn_stock_total_euro", "$" + CoverageWarningFieldEnum.VAL_PN_STOCK_TOTAL_EURO.getLabel())
                            , sum("sum_val_pn_average_sale_12month_euro", "$" + CoverageWarningFieldEnum.VAL_PN_AVERAGE_SALE_12MONTH_EURO.getLabel())
                            , sum("sum_score", "$" + CoverageWarningFieldEnum.SCORE.getLabel())),
                    Aggregates.sort(Sorts.orderBy(Sorts.descending(CoverageWarningFieldEnum.SCORE.getLabel())))
            ));
```

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. What happens when you append the count stage (`Aggregates.count("totalCount");`) to see no of documents your aggregation returns ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong.

Aggregate is a "group by" operation. That is why is it grouping your result set into 500 groups.

This explains clearly about aggregation grouping https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/

If you want to load all records then use mongo "find" operation.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

Comment: the problem i should make it by group because it's a select distinct . how can i do a select distinct(SQL) and all the Sum and got all the documents ...

Comment: You are talking about three different operations.
1. Mongo distinct operation to get all distinct documents based on some filters.
2. Mongo Aggregation operation to compute sum.
3. Mongo find operation to get all documents.

I do not think all these operations are possible in a single query.

Comment: Yes i'm talking about the Sum , distinct and sort

Comment: i can't do it with a simple find .... if you think i can , can you please give me an exemple

Comment: I'll suggest you to go with multiple queries to achieve the result.

Comment: it's really complex ... to do it because i will do an aggregate match for more than 100000 object ...

Comment: Check if this is helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24761266/select-group-by-count-and-distinct-count-in-same-mongodb-query