# Count distinct in MongoDB not giving distinct results

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am a SQL user struggling with NoSQL.

I am looking for an alternative in MongoDB for a query like:

`select city, count(distinct device) from collection group by city, devicetype`

My collection is like:

```
{
"city":"city1",
"device": "device1"
"deviceType":1
},
{
"city":"city1",
"device": "device2"
"deviceType":0
},
{
"city":"city1",
"device": "device3"
"deviceType":1
},
{
"city":"city1",
"device": "device2"
"deviceType":0
}
```

After grouping, I need *distinct* devices used by their `devicetype` of each city.

In other words, the output would be like:

```
{
"city":"city1",
"deviceType":0,
"deviceCount":1     //device2
},
{
"city":"city1",
"deviceType":1,
"deviceCount":2     //device1, device3
}
```

I tried:

```
"$group": {
                _id: { "city": "$city", "devicetype": "$devicetype" },
                "devicetype": { "$first": "$devicetype" },
                "count": { "$sum": 1 }
            }
```

I am getting the total count of devices, not the distinct count. What can I try next?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24761266/select-group-by-count-and-distinct-count-in-same-mongodb-query

read last answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    _id: {
      "city": "$city",
      "deviceType": "$deviceType"
    },
    "deviceCount": { "$addToSet": "$device" },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "city": "$_id.city",
    "deviceType": "$_id.deviceType",
    "deviceCount": { "$size": "$deviceCount" }
  }}
])
```

[**Output**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/n7SggQDzXkW)

```
[
  {
    "city": "city1",
    "deviceCount": 1,
    "deviceType": 0
  },
  {
    "city": "city1",
    "deviceCount": 2,
    "deviceType": 1
  }
]
```