# MongoDB query similar to SELECT COUNT GROUP BY

Tags: mongodb

My MongoDB database has the 'interviews' collection whose document structure is similar to this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("632b97b0f2bd3f64bbc30ec8"),
    "agency" : "AG1",
    "year" : "2022",
    "month" : "9",
    "residents" : [
        {
            "sequential" : 1,
            "name" : "Resident 1",
            "statusResident" : "pending",
        },
        {
            "sequential" : 2,
            "name" : "Resident 2",
            "statusResident" : "not analyzed"
        },
        {
            "sequential" : 3,
            "name" : "Resident 3",
            "statusResident" : "not analyzed"
        },
        {
            "sequential" : 4,
            "name" : "Resident 4",
            "statusResident" : "finished"
        }
    ]
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("882b99b0f2bd3f64xxc30ec8"),
    "agency" : "AG2",
    "year" : "2022",
    "month" : "9",
    "residents" : [
        {
            "sequential" : 1,
            "name" : "Resident 10",
            "statusResident" : "pending",
        },
        {
            "sequential" : 2,
            "name" : "Resident 20",
            "statusResident" : "not analyzed"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to make a query that returns something similar to SQL `SELECT agency, statusResident, COUNT(*) FROM interviews GROUP BY agency, statusResident`.

For these documents above, that would return something like

```
AG1     pending        1
AG1     not analyzed   2
AG1     finished       1
AG2     pending        1
AG2     not analyzed   1
```

I ran the following queries but they didn't return what I need:

```
db.interviews.aggregate([
                 { $group: { _id: { agency: "$agency", statusResident: "$residents.statusResident", total: { $sum: "$residents.statusResident" } } } },
                 { $sort: { agency: 1 } } 
               


db.interviews.group({
    key:{agency:1, "residents.statusResident":1},
    cond:{year:2022},
    reduce:function(current, result)
       {
         result.total += 1;
       },
         initial:{total:0}
       })
```

I've consulted post "[MongoDB SELECT COUNT GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23116330/mongodb-select-count-group-by)" and "[Select count group by mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739438/select-count-group-by-mongodb)" as well as the MongoDB documentation but to no avail. What query should I run to get a result similar to the one I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this query:

- First `$unwind` to deconstruct the array and can group by `statusResident` too.
- Then `$group` by two values, `agency` and `statusResident`.
- And the last stage is `$project` to get an easier to read output.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$residents"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "agency": "$agency",
        "statusResident": "$residents.statusResident"
      },
      "total": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "agency": "$_id.agency",
      "statusResident": "$_id.statusResident",
      "total": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sIHK1IdouTO)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I need to study this ``$unwind`` better and evaluate the result on a larger basis, but apparently it's perfect. I chose best answer for the ``$project`` suggestion, which delivers a more readable answer. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$residents" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        agency: "$agency",
        statusResident: "$residents.statusResident",
        total: { $sum: 1 }
      }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { agency: 1 } }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hobpMySiLMR)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I need to study this ``$unwind`` better and evaluate the result on a larger basis, but apparently it's perfect. Thank you so much!